# Python/wxPython: ImportError: No module named lib.buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have installed **wxPython** using **wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.0.0-py27.exe** (recommended; reinstalled bunch of times to make sure that would not help) on Windows 8. At the end of installation it asked if it should compile **wxPython**'s **py** files. I chose to compile; no errors.

I have `import wx` and `import wx.lib.buttons as buttons` in my **py** file (my code).

`print wx` says: `<module 'wx' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\wx\__init__.pyc'>` (Why PyInstaller? I have reinstalled `wxPython` and chose it to be the default `wx` package).

`print sys.executable` sys: `C:\Python27\python.exe`.

`print sys.path` says:

```
['C:\\zone_workspace\\cef\\cefpython-tut\\examples', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg', 
'C:\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\cefpython3', 
'C:\\wxPython-Docs-and-Demos', 
'C:\\zone_workspace\\cef\\cefpython-tut\\examples', 
'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 
'C:\\Python27', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-3.0-msw']
```

As we can see `'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-3.0-msw'` is in `sys.path`.

And the `wx.pth` file is in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` path containing just `wx-3.0-msw`; the name of the directory that exists there and contains the `wx` package.

Even PyCharm recognized `wx` package and does its **pyfu** perfectly.

Strange that it recognizes `wx` but not `wx.lib.buttons` (in `import wx.lib.buttons as buttons`).

What is going on?

Comment: you need to fix your path to take pyinstaller off of it ... or at least behind site-packages directories  wx.__file__ for me is `C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\\wx\\__init__.pyc`

Comment: How can I remove or overwrite the PyInstaller wx path? (Excuse me; I am not a Python developer - yet).

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were two problems; first there was `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\wx` which I have renamed to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\wx_renamed` and second one was `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\cefpython3\wx` which I have renamed to `C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\cefpython3\wx_renamed`. Both of these directories contain helper code for `wx` not the `wx` itself.

Hope this helps other Python new comers.